# Make selected <li> vary in width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get a ul to have varying widths. This `ul` is flexed and I want the first two items in the `ul` (which will be in one column`to be 60% in width and the last two items 40%. But my`flex-basis` isn't working?

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  height: 125px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

/* li:nth-child(1), 
li:nth-child(2){ 
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

li:nth-child(3), 
li:nth-child(4){ 
  flex-basis: 40%;
} */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>should be 60%</li>
    <li>should be 60%</li>
    <li>should be 40%</li>
    <li>should be 40%</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-basis consider the main axis, so you need width here

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the left padding on the `<ul>` (I assume that's what you want) and simply specify the width using `width` instead of `flex-basis`:

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  height: 125px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul li{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

li:nth-child(1), 
li:nth-child(2){ 
  width: 60%;
}

li:nth-child(3), 
li:nth-child(4){ 
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>should be 60%</li>
    <li>should be 60%</li>
    <li>should be 40%</li>
    <li>should be 40%</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```